# JSON JQ filter by date older than bash

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a json with this format of data in a text.json file

```
[
  {
    "name": "page/page1.html",
    "properties": {
      "lastModified": "2021-08-10T18:00:45+00:00",
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "page/page2.html",
    "properties": {
      "lastModified": "2021-08-10T19:24:23+00:00",
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "page/page3.html",
    "properties": {
      "lastModified": "2021-08-10T20:36:21+00:00",
    }
  }
]
```

I want to make a list of all the names of files which are last modified more that 30 minutes ago. This is my query at the moment to get a list of file names as a variable which i can use later.

```
file_names=`cat text.json | jq -r .[].name`
```

How can I use jq to filter for lastModified more than 30 minutes ago based on the timestamp in the properties so I only get the relevant file names?

Comment: The beautiful thing about this particular date format is that a normal string comparison will work.

Comment: BTW, don't use `cat json.txt | jq ...`; instead, use `jq ... json.txt` on `jq ... <json.txt`. (That's a general rule, not specific to jq -- when a tool has a direct file handle instead of a FIFO, it both can read faster and also has more room to optimize -- having different threads read different parts of the file in parallel, or checking the size before starting, or being able to implement multi-pass logic without buffering in memory, or so forth; a pipe can only be read front-to-back, exactly once, with no ability to jump around or reread, etc)

Comment: BTW, the sample data in the question isn't valid JSON -- I think you didn't take the extra commas out when trying to minimize it.

Comment: BTW, storing filenames in a string is generally not a sound idea. A filename can contain newlines. If someone runs `d=/tmp/deleteme/$'\n'/etc/passwd$'\n'/gotcha; mkdir "$d" && touch "$d/badfile"` and then you pipe from `find /tmp -name badfile -print` into something that runs `rm` for each line, you're going to have a very, very bad day.

Comment: ...by contrast, NUL characters can't exist in filenames, so they're safe to use to delimit filenames in a list; but because NULs are used to terminate C strings, you can't store a list that contains NULs in a C string (such as those used by standard POSIX-y shells). Thus, needing to use an array to safely store lists of arbitrary filenames.

Comment: hem1234 - Please indicate whether all the timezone offsets in the relevant timestamps are guaranteed to be the same in the incoming JSON.

Answer (score 1):

I'd typically calculate the target date in native bash.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# make sure we have bash new enough for printf %(...)T time-formatting
# this makes our script work even without GNU date
case $BASH_VERSION in
  ''|[123].*|4.[012].*) echo "ERROR: bash 4.3+ required" >&2; exit 1;;
esac

export TZ=UTC # force all timestamps to be in UTC (+00:00 / Z)

# faster, bash-builtin now=$(date +%s)
printf -v now '%(%s)T' -1

# faster, bash-builtin start_date_iso8601=$(date +%s -d '30 minutes ago')
start_date_epoch=$((now - 60*30))
printf -v start_date_iso8601 '%(%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+00:00)T' "$start_date_epoch"

# read our resulting names into an array (not a string)
# jq -j suppresses newlines so we can use NUL delimiters
while IFS= read -r -d '' name; do
  names+=( "$name" )
done < <(
  jq -j --arg start_date "$start_date_iso8601" '
    .[] |
    select(.properties.lastModified < $start_date) |
    (.name, "\u0000")
  ' <text.json
)

# print the content of the array we just read the names into
printf 'Matching name: %q\n' "${names[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

```
date=`date +%Y-%m-%d'T'%H:%M'Z' -d "15 min ago"`

file_names=`jq -r --arg date "$date" '.[] | select(.properties.lastModified < $date) | .name' < text.json`
```

Comment: Certainly does work; it's a fair bit less efficient than doing the date math in native bash, but on the other hand, it works with older versions of bash. (Is that why you thought it was worth adding a new/additional answer?).

Comment: Oh, one other thing -- this answer won't work right unless your system's timezone is UTC. If `date` spits out a time in local time and your local time _isn't_ UTC, you might get 15 minutes + whatever-that-offset-is. So you might want `export TZ=UTC` in your answer too, or if you're targeting GNU date, to use `--utc`.

Comment: (Also, this answer only works with GNU date; BSD date, as found on MacOS, doesn't support using `-d '15 minutes ago'`)

Answer (score 0):

Let `jq` do all date computations:

With bash 4 and above with `mapfile`:

```sh
mapfile -d '' last_modified < <(
  jq --join-output '(now - 1800) as $date | .[] | select((.properties.lastModified | .[:18] + "Z" | fromdate) < $date) | .name + "\u0000"' input_file.json
)

# For debug purpose
declare -p last_modified
```

Without `mapfile`, records are delimited with ASCII `RS` control character rather than a `null` byte:

```sh
IFS=$'\36' read -ra last_modified < <(jq -j '(now - 1800) as $date | .[] | select((.properties.lastModified | .[:18] + "Z" | fromdate) < $date) | .name + "\u001e"' input_file.json)
```

Here is the stand-alone `jq` script with comments:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S jq -jf

# Store current timestamp minus 30 minutes (1800 seconds) as $date
(now - 1800) as $date |
 .[] |
#
select(
  (
    # Strip the numerical timezone offset out from the timestamp
    # and replace it with the Z for UTC iso8601
    # to make it an iso8601 date string that jq understands
    .properties.lastModified | .[:18] + "Z" | fromdate
  ) < $date
) |
.name + "\u0000"
```

Comment: With respect to the advice "Let jq do all date computations" please note that jq's handling of dates currently has some deficiencies, the worst of which is a silent bug affecting the interaction between TZ and strftime.  One way to check date/time processing is to use gojq, the Go implementation of jq.

Comment: @peak I tried to get `gojq` into my Ubuntu and gave-up because there is no distribution of it. I won't install a go coding suite or docker just for a command to run in shells. About `silent bug affecting the interaction between TZ and strftime` which is https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/929 with all due respect, it is the fault of MacOS's C-Library not handling the `%Z` date format indicator.

Comment: I believe you should be able to install gojq on linux machines using homebrew (formerly  linuxbrew). The silent bug I was referring to concerns strflocaltime and has nothing to do  with  strptime.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/jimmidyson/asdf-gojq